# Try Catch method for open bluetooth function

Tags: android, bluetooth

I made a simple android appication for connect with bluetooth serial device and I want to add `closeBT` if android not connected maybe the device is out of range because crash.

How do I do this? This code is correct?

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    findBT(); //Check if bluettoth enable and paired devices

    try {
        openBT(); //open sockets,streams
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        closeBT();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Try-catch` is not for the application logic! It is for doing stuff when something went wrong! You want to use an `if-else` here, like

```
if (findBT() != null) { // I don't know what findBT does, but maybe it returns BT-devices
    try {
        openBT(); //open sockets,streams
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // inform the user that a connection could not be established or something similar
    }
} else {
    // inform the user, that no BT-device was found.
}
```

you want to use `closeBT()` for instance when the user or your application decides to disconnect the BT-devices.

Comment: If you want to inform the user, a Toast or a DialogBox is helpful.